# How to implement chat features in Android application?

Tags: android, chat

I am making an application in which I need to implement chat features. We have our own server from we get friends list from the server.

I need to send msg to that friends and get reply message from that friends. For this I think I have to send msg to server of that friend in which I have to chat.

But I am unable to understand how to get reply from the server of a chat message.
Please help

Comment: question is not clear, If you want to write Chat first you must implement its concept. You can implement chat by using Server and storing data to the server or
you can do that with Peer To Peer connection (Just directly sending messages from user to user), or even you can mix them. it is up to how you want to craft

Answer (score 1):

You can use different APIs to implement the chat feature. Here is the link for sample open source chat application which using [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/) api.

http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/

see the [sample](http://people.apache.org/~dims/android/XMPPClient.zip) application which is based XMPP protocol. You can configure your google account for testing.

Comment: my concept is that we have our own server in which i get users list in a listview  i need to send msg to the user to which i need for chat .i think i will send msg to server and server send that msg to GCM and through GCm it send send msg to friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the chat features either by using third party API like (Smack ,Asmack) or by implementing your client server logic. I will prefer you to use above API for implementing chat features in your application.